# .net OracleDependency OnChangeEventHandler problems with bulk insert

Tags: c#, odp.net, bulk

I am doing some tests using `OracleDependency` and `OnChangeEventHandler`

I have created an event handler with this signature:

```
void dep_OnChange(object sender, OracleNotificationEventArgs args)
```

The query I am monitoring is this:

```
"select * from TESTTABLE";
```

where `TESTTABLE` is a very simple table with 2 columns.

The event gets fired when I insert records in TESTTABLE as expected, also when I delete records or update them.

The problem I am experiencing is related to the insert: when I insert a limited number of records, say less than 100 and commit the change, everything works as expected and via the ROWID, I can get the IDS of the inserted records in the event handler, which is what I want.
However, when I insert more than 100 records, this does not work anymore. The event gets fired (even more than once for the same commit statement) but I cannot retrieve the ROWIDs of the newly inserted records.

Is there anything I should do on the database side to make sure the notifications are sent anyway even when affecting a great number of records?

Regards